# Tooltip: Preload data OR ajax on request

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a list of families where each family - on rollover - display a tooltip with additional information about individual family (living place info and 3 images of that place).

So what is the best practice (performance) to do? To preload all the data at the beginning or to ajax request data only when needed (on rollover)?

Note that page already includes 3 select mysql_queries, and data fetch for tooltip requires another 2.

***Queries (for the idea of search complexity):***

**Original 3 queries:**

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY bDate DESC LIMIT 5;
SELECT * FROM family ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5;
SELECT bplace.placeID, bplace.sName, bplace.countryID, bcountry.regionID FROM bplace, bcountry WHERE bplace.countryID = bcountry.countryID ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5;
```

**Tooltip 2 queries (preload way):**

```
while(...){

$allFamilies[] = $row["familyID"];

}

$allFamilies = implode(',',$allFamilies);

SELECT sName FROM bplace WHERE placeID IN ($allfamilies);
SELECT url FROM images WHERE placeID IN ($allfamilies);
```

**Tooltip 2 queries (ajax way):**

```
SELECT sName FROM bplace WHERE placeID='1';
SELECT url FROM images WHERE placeID='1';
```

Comment: I think ajax would be a good option as it does not require to reload the page, preloading can be expensive if the all the family data is huge

Comment: This totally depends on your desired user experience.  You could do a mix even and load the basic data initially and then load ALL rollover content after initial page load.  ALso it seem that for your rollover queries you could reduce to a single query like `SELECT bplace.sName, images.url FROM bplace JOIN url ON bplace.placeID = images.placeID WHERE placeID = ?`

Answer (score 2):

I think it is all preference with a little bit of common sense.  A thousand rows preloaded will take a bit of time to grab, loop, and then display (making the page size a few kb bigger).  If it is just a few rows being grabbed, then it probably makes sense to just grab those rows rather than waiting for AJAX to load them.

Another thing to think about is, will the data change and will it change often.  If the tooltip data is constantly being changed, then AJAX may be the way to go regardless.  If it is mostly static, then grabbing it all together probably makes sense.

Ajax can take time, but unless your server is very high volume and you haven't grown accordingly, those requests only take fractions of a second.

Ultimately, it is personal preference.  What would be easier for you?  Would hard coding each tool tip be easier, or would it be easier to call the tooltip data using javascript?  Go with what is easier and seems to flow better with your site.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to think how big your application will grow. Your IN queries are really going to slow down if you get a few thousand rows. The ajax queries will always load fast as they are direct lookups.

Also if the data can be cached, serving the ajax calls directly to a CDN would make it load almost instantly. If your constantly pulling data and need to scale the ajax method could also be used on a keystore as it is primary key look up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a general, definitive answer to your question.

To measure some kind of performance you have to take alot more variables into account, p.e.

- how many tooltips will be loaded per page,
- how big is the data they
  return,
- how's the connection between client & server and server &
  database,
- how long do the queries take,
- how many users browse
  through those pages at the same time,
- is caching involved

and many more.

I had a very similar question during a project a while back (it related to tooltips too), and I went the ajax way, mainly because I wanted to speed up the initial pageload as much as possible (less script duration, less html size). If many users would browse through all of the tooltips at the same time, then the ajax way would actually eat more "performance", but that plainly wasn't the case in this project.